# Custom toolbar button in NetBeans for clean/build/debug

Tags: button, netbeans, build, module, toolbar

I want to create a custom toolbar button that performs a "Clean" (without the "Build") and after it finishes, it instantly starts Debugging. (and also a separate button that does Clean and Build and then debugs)

I managed to create a module with an icon and some code i got with the help of chat GPT but it does nothing,
i have zero experience with APIs so i don't know how to search for stuff on the netbeans api documentation

Reason: I have to constantly do it every few code changes and i waste so much time forgetting i hit Clean and Build (takes almost 2 minutes to finish in my project) waiting for the web app to appear (which it does when i hit Debug, catching my attention so i can start testing)

I don't think this code will be of much help, it's the only one gpt provided that didn't have various dependency problems (it only provided the stuff inside actionPerformed(ActionEvent e))

```
package CleanBuildDebug;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReferences;
import org.openide.awt.ActionRegistration;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;

@ActionID(
        category = "CleanBuildDebug",
        id = "CleanBuildDebug.CleanBuildDebug"
)
@ActionRegistration(
        iconBase = "CleanBuildDebug/CleanDebug.png",
        displayName = "#CTL_CleanBuildDebug"
)
@ActionReferences({
  @ActionReference(path = "Menu/File", position = 0),
  @ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/File", position = 0)
})
@Messages("CTL_CleanBuildDebug=CleanBuildDebug")
public final class CleanBuildDebug implements ActionListener {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Execute Clean and Build
    try {
      Process cleanProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ant -f nbproject/build-impl.xml clean jar");
      cleanProcess.waitFor();

      // Execute Debug
      Process debugProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ant -f nbproject/build-impl.xml -Drun.class=your.main.class debug");
      debugProcess.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
      // Handle any exceptions here
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```